# Multiple synced owl carousel

Tags: javascript, jquery, owl-carousel

I've edited the code provided from [here](https://web.archive.org/web/20161125160505/http://owlgraphic.com/owlcarousel/demos/sync.html) to cater for two carousel without it being id dependent, which works fine, except that I can't get the tabs to work properly upon click. (E.g, removing the class "synced" and adding them onto the clicked tab properly.) Think I'm not doing something right with both **function syncPosition** and **function left**.

Where did I miss out, or did wrong?

HTML:

```
<!--Carousel 1-->
<div class="tabslider">
  <div class="owl-carousel tabthumb">
    <div class="item" >1</div>
    <div class="item" >2</div>
    <div class="item" >3</div>
    <div class="item" >4</div>
    <div class="item" >5</div>
  </div>
  <div class="owl-carousel tabcontent">
    <div class="item">Content 1</div>
    <div class="item">Content 2</div>
    <div class="item">Content 3</div>
    <div class="item">Content 4</div>
    <div class="item">Content 5</div>
  </div>
</div>
<!--Carousel 2-->
<div class="tabslider">
<div class="owl-carousel tabthumb">
  <div class="item" >1</div>
  <div class="item" >2</div>
  <div class="item" >3</div>
  <div class="item" >4</div>
</div>
<div class="owl-carousel tabcontent">
  <div class="item">Content 1</div>
  <div class="item">Content 2</div>
  <div class="item">Content 3</div>
  <div class="item">Content 4</div>
</div>
```

Script:

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function() {

      $('.tabslider').each(function(){

        var sync1 = $(this).children(".tabcontent");
        var sync2 = $(this).children(".tabthumb");

        sync1.owlCarousel({
          singleItem : true,
          slideSpeed : 1000,
          pagination:false,
          afterAction : syncPosition,
          responsiveRefreshRate : 200,
        });

        sync2.owlCarousel({
          items : 3,
          itemsDesktop      : [1199,3],
          itemsDesktopSmall     : [979,3],
          itemsTablet       : [768,2],
          itemsMobile       : [479,2],
          pagination:false,
          navigation: false,
          navigationText: [
            "<i class='icon-arrow-left7'></i>",
            "<i class='icon-uniE6E2'></i>"
          ],
          responsiveRefreshRate : 100,
          afterInit : function(el){
            el.find(".owl-item").eq(0).addClass("synced");
          }
        });

        function syncPosition(el){
          var current = this.currentItem;
          // $(".tabthumb")
          $(this).find(".tabthumb")
            .find(".owl-item")
            .removeClass("synced")
            .eq(current)
            .addClass("synced")

          if($(this).children(".tabthumb").data("owlCarousel") !== undefined){
            left(current)
            console.log(this)
          }

        }

        $(this).children(".tabthumb").on("click", ".owl-item", function(e){
          e.preventDefault();
          var number = $(this).data("owlItem");
          sync1.trigger("owl.goTo",number);

        });

        function left(number){
          var sync2visible = sync2.data("owlCarousel").owl.visibleItems;

          var num = number;
          var found = false;
          for(var i in sync2visible){
            if(num === sync2visible[i]){
              var found = true;
            }
          }

          if(found===false){
            if(num>sync2visible[sync2visible.length-1]){
              sync2.trigger("owl.goTo", num - sync2visible.length+2)
            }else{
              if(num - 1 === -1){
                num = 0;
              }
              sync2.trigger("owl.goTo", num);
            }
          } else if(num === sync2visible[sync2visible.length-1]){
            sync2.trigger("owl.goTo", sync2visible[1])
          } else if(num === sync2visible[0]){
            sync2.trigger("owl.goTo", num-1)
          }
        }

      })

    });
    </script>
```

Answer (score 1):

JS:

```
//remove the following(and its closing tag of course) :   

   $('.tabslider').each(function(){


//modify this part: 
$(this).children(".tabthumb").on("click", ".owl-item", function(e)
{
    //we modify our trigger to only apply to our current gallery, not all of them
    e.preventDefault();
    var number = $(this).data("owlItem");

    //The navigation with the thumbnails
    var $thumbnailNavWrapper = $(this).closest('your-thumbnail-navigation-class');

    //the slider with the big images .prev or .next depending on
 whether we find our slider before or next to the thumbnail navigation
    $sync1 = $thumbnailNavWrapper.prev();

    sync1.trigger("owl.goTo",number);

});
```

If the above is not enough and you need a thumbnail nav with a "centerized" style.

```
function center(number){
    var sync2visible = $sync2.data("owlCarousel").owl.visibleItems;
    var num = number;


    if(num === sync2visible[0])
    {
      $sync2.trigger("owl.goTo", num-1);
    }
    else if(sync2visible.length <= 2)
    {
      $sync2.trigger("owl.goTo", num+1);
    }

    else
    {
      $sync2.trigger("owl.goTo", num-1);
    }
  }
```

Not sure if this will 100% help. Just made mine with the same issue.

Answer (score 0):

```
Simply use Each method for the owl carousel's sync slider.
You can target CSS things by common classes and use ID with each method in JS selectors.
```

For your reference: check this URL.

[Codepen Link] https://codepen.io/ajay-rathore/pen/gOZXNda

```html
<iframe height="300" style="width: 100%;" scrolling="no" title="Owl Carousel 2 uses of multiple sync sliders demo with loop/autoplay" src="https://codepen.io/ajay-rathore/embed/gOZXNda?default-tab=html%2Cresult" frameborder="no" loading="lazy" allowtransparency="true" allowfullscreen="true">
  See the Pen <a href="https://codepen.io/ajay-rathore/pen/gOZXNda">
  Owl Carousel 2 uses of multiple sync sliders demo with loop/autoplay</a> by Ajay Rathore (<a href="https://codepen.io/ajay-rathore">@ajay-rathore</a>)
  on <a href="https://codepen.io">CodePen</a>.
</iframe>
```